# Laravel : Extends Controller not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

when trying to get data and returns it via transformers got an error `Class 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Auth\\ApiController' not found`. Using ApiController to extends.I put APIcontroller to `App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Front` folder.

LoginController Code and extends it to ApiController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Api\V1\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use App\User;
use App\UserDeviceData;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Transformers\UserTransformer;

class LoginController extends ApiController // extends to API controller
{
    public function login(LoginRequest $request, JWTAuth $JWTAuth)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        try {
            $token = Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials);
            if(!$token) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => "Email and password do not match",
                    'status_code' => 403,
                ]);
            }

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->last_login = Carbon::now();
            $user->save();

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->UserDeviceData()->firstOrCreate([
                'device_id' => $request->device_id
            ]);


        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Internal server error",
                'status_code' => 500,
            ]);
        }
        return $this->response->collection($user, new UserTransformer);
    }
}
```

Api controller code : and set `namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers\Front;`

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers\Front;

use App\Support\Response;
use App\Support\Parameters;

abstract class ApiController extends Controller
{

    protected $response;
    protected $parameters;

    public function __construct(Response $response, Parameters $parameters)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }
}
```

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ApiController` and `LoginController` are using a different namespace, you need to `use` your `ApiController` in `LoginController`.

```
use App\Api\V1\Controllers\Front\ApiController;
```

You also forgot to `use` `Controller` in `ApiController`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Comment: `Class 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\Front\\Controller' not found` now in Front folder..